# Jquery Image slider showing thumbnails on bullets hover

Tags: php, html, jquery-plugins

Is there any responsive jQuery plugin for displaying image slider and also  showing thumbnails on bullets hover.
Tried LayerSlider plugin but the whole image was not visible.
Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple that come to mind wowslider or sliderrevolution.I think both should fit this need for you.

Comment: it should be similar to LayerSlider. Please refer the url : http://kreaturamedia.com/layerslider-responsive-jquery-slider-plugin/

Comment: bottom portion of the image slider, bullets are shown and on hover, thumbnails are shown

Answer (score 0):

see this url you will get some idea http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl its working good  `enter code here  http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl`

Comment: use some font awesome icons inside the anchor tag with your image

Answer (score 0):

There doesnt seem to be much cloice if your against LayerSlider 
you could implement one yourself with something like this with the hover function instead ?

```
var mainImage = $("#mainImage");
$(".img-container img").hover(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  $("#mainImage").attr("src",src);
});

mainImage.on("click",function(){
   $(this).css("transform","scale(2)");
});
```